# How to pass a variable to a new window (WindowGroup)?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I'm trying to use the new WindowGroup to display a more complex view in a new window but somehow I can't figure out how to pass values into the view. 
Until yet I was playing around with NSWindow but there I can't use the new toolbar with `.toolbar{}` and I'm somehow getting weird errors when using the latest swiftUI features.
In my old code I just could pass my values into the new view like usual:

```swift
.simultaneousGesture(TapGesture(count: 2).onEnded {

      var window: NSWindow!

      if nil == window {
           let serverView = serverView(content: content) // parse my struct content(name: "XServe-Test", configFile: "/FileUrl", permissions: .rootPermissions, cluster: cluster(x12, CPUMax: .cores(28), ramMax: .gb(1200)))
           window = NSWindow(
           contentRect: NSRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 580, height: 400),
           styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable, .fullSizeContentView],
            backing: .buffered,
            defer: false)
            window.center()
            window.setFrameAutosaveName("ServerMainView")
            window.isReleasedWhenClosed = false
            window.title = content.name
            window.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: serverView)
            window.toolbar = NSToolbar()
            window.toolbarStyle = .unifiedCompact
         }

      window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
 }
```

Now I'm using in the app file:

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct myApp: App {
    
    var body: some Scene {

        WindowGroup {
            contentView()
        }.windowStyle(HiddenTitleBarWindowStyle())
        .commands {
            SidebarCommands()
            ToolbarCommands()
        }

        // the view that should be displayed in a new window 
        WindowGroup("serverView") {
            let inputContent : content = content(name: "XServe-Test", configFile: "/FileUrl", permissions: .rootPermissions, cluster: cluster(x12, CPUMax: .cores(28), ramMax: .gb(1200))) 
            serverView(content: inputContent) // this is static now :(
        }.handlesExternalEvents(matching: Set(arrayLiteral: "serverView"))
}
```

and the following code to open the view:

```swift
  .simultaneousGesture(TapGesture(count: 2).onEnded {

  guard let url = URL(string: "com-code-myApp://serverView") else { return }
        NSWorkspace.shared.open(url)
}
```

How do I pass the input from the tap gesture into the new view using the WindowGroup logic?

Comment: I'm looking for a similar solution. Did you find a way to do this?

Comment: @ZS check out my answer!

Answer (score 2):

I found two ways to solve this problem. I'm using the first one, because my application is file based. The second solution is based on the great [Pulse](https://github.com/kean/Pulse) git repo.
In both cases you need to register a custom URL in the Xcode project settings under: 
Tragets -> yourApp -> Info -> URL Types, otherwise it won't work.

first solution:

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct myApp: App {
     
    var body: some Scene {
        // 'default' view
        WindowGroup { contentView() }
 
        // the view that should open if someone opens your file
        WindowGroup("fileView") { fileView() }
        .handlesExternalEvents(matching: ["file"]) // does the magic
 
    }
}

struct fileView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{ /* your view content */}
        .onOpenURL(perform: { url in
            // get url and read e.g.: your info file
        })
    }
}



// you can open a file using:
Button("openMyFileinAnExtraWindow"){
   let fileUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: "~/Documents/myFile.yourExtension")
   NSWorkspace.shared.open(fileUrl)
}
```

second solution:

> Notice: I created this code snippet based on the great [Pulse](https://github.com/kean/Pulse) git repo.

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct myApp: App {

    var body: some Scene {
        // 'default' view
        WindowGroup { contentView() }

        // the view that should open if someone opens your file
        WindowGroup { DetailsView() }
        .handlesExternalEvents(matching: Set(arrayLiteral: "newWindow")) // this url must be registerd

    }
}

struct DetailsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ExternalEvents.open
    }
}

public struct ExternalEvents {
    /// - warning: Don't use it, it's used internally.
    public static var open: AnyView?
}

struct contentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // create a button that opens a new window
            Button("open a new window") {
                ExternalEvents.open = AnyView(
                    newWindow(id: 0, WindowName: "I am a new window!" )
                )
                guard let url = URL(string: "your-url://newWindow") else { return }
                NSWorkspace.shared.open(url)
            }
            
        }
    }
}

struct newWindow: View {
    var id: Int
    var WindowName: String
    var body: some View{
        VStack{
            Text(WindowName + String(id))
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if this is the best way to pass variables to a new window, but it does the job quite convincingly.
I'm happy about any solution approaches and ideas.

Comment: Thanks for the update. But in the first solution, I'm not clear how to pass in the filename that you want to open from the Tap Gesture recognizer to the new window you want to open. Do you still call `NSWorkspace.shared.open(url)`? And the `fileView` can handle it without needing to register as a URL type?

Comment: @ZS Yes you just open file via `NSWorkspace.shared.open(fileUrl)` or by double clicking it on the finder, I'm not sure if it is working with lets say a .txt file or only with custom files like .myFile etc.. Im using my own exported type identifier and it's working fine - even when opening the file with the terminal.

Comment: Thanks. I did get it to work now. I'm pretty sure that one would have to add the URL scheme even in the first example you showed. If you can add the details in your answer on how to invoke the URL (which you put in the question), I'll mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: @ZS I added the two details.

Answer (score 2):

I found this example at [Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/windowgroup)

First, You need `Codable` & `Hashable` struct for your data. For example, If I would like to pass an url when opening a view:

```swift
struct File: Codable, Hashable {
    var id = UUID()
    let path: URL
}
```

Now we can pass this struct between windows.

```swift
@main
struct myApp: App {
     
    var body: some Scene {
        // Default View
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        
        // Open FileView() with given data.
        WindowGroup(id: "file.view", for: File.self) { $file in
            FileView(file: $file)
        } default: {  // fallback
            File(path: URL(string: ""))
        }
    }
}
```

FileView should look like below:

```swift
struct FileView: View {
    @Binding var file: File

    var body: some View{
        Text(file.path.absoluteString)
    }
}
```

You can open FileView() everywhere. This is an example to open FileView() with data in ContentView()

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.openWindow) private var openWindow
    @Environment(\.dismissWindow) private var dismissWindow

    var body: some View{
        Button("hit me") {
            openWindow(id: "file.view", value: File(path: URL(string: "file://")!)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Naming a property of type `URL` "path" is confusing. I'd stick with "url".